# Reverse String in Lua?

Tags: string, function, lua, character, reverse

I am trying to reverse a string in Lua without using the string.reverse() function. Here is my code -

```
 function reverseStr(s)
   return string.gsub(s, "(.)(.)", "%2%1")
 end
```

The code is currently only reversing the first two characters in the string, and I am wondering what I can do to make the function reverse *every* character in the string.

abc -- cba
bbc -- cbb
dka -- akd

Thank you!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can't make Lua's pattern matching system reverse a string. You have to either write the obvious reversing code (iterating through the string backwards, building a new table from strings in reverse order, and using `table.concat`) or use `string.reverse`.

Comment: I love how you left the good stuff to the end. I was going to iterate through the string beckwards, but you saved me a few lines of code. `string.reverse(str)` works great

Comment: If you'll for whatever reason EVER try to implement reverse yourself, use table + `table.concat` instead of adding one char per time.